# Is there a way to style css in groups according to its parent?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to write css in groups according to its parent so I don't need to re write the parent's name over and over again, for example:

```
.firstparent {
    .firstchild { background: red }
    .secondchild { background: orange }
    .thirdchild .grandchild { background: green }
    /* This will only affect the elements with the class name that is the child of firstparent *??
}

.secondparent {
    div { background: blue }
    .firstchild { background: black }
}

/* Right now I am writing as below */

.firstparent .firstchild { background: red }
.firstparent .secondchild { background: orange }
.firstparent .thirdchild .grandchild { background: green }

.secondparent div { background: blue }
.secondparent .firstchild { background: black }
```

Rather than keep re writing the parent's name over and over again is there a way to write the css as I showed above ?

Comment: If it's just for the organization purposes use pre-processors like SASS or LESS. They do exactly what you want.

Comment: @holodoc Thank you this is exactly what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS pre-processors like `SASS`/`LESS` help you to nest children inside your parent elements. They also allow you nest active element states, pseudo elements etc relative to the parent element.

For more info, and to get a kickstart check the [sass basics guide](http://sass-lang.com/guide)

For detailed info, refer the [sass reference guide](http://www.sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html).

Comment: Thank you, I never knew there are CSS pre-processors like SASS / LESS, thanks for the link too.

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla CSS does not support nesting of selectors and blocks the way you want them. As the other answers have already hinted, the current state-of-art necessitates the use of CSS pre-processors like LESS, SASS or Stylus. The question for an adopter is then which preprocessor to choose.

I would argue that popularity of LESS has waned, with SASS being the most popular option now. Bootstrap, for example, has moved on from LESS to SASS. SASS, however is non-trivial to setup in an existing vanilla HTML/CSS/Javascript project - you need a build system that can generate the CSS files, e.g. Grunt/Webpack/etc. with live-reload and all them other fancy new toys.

LESS, being a superset of CSS, has a small learning curve and can be used as a drop-in replacement for CSS. You just link the LESS stylesheets in your project and use the in-browser LESS compiler:

```
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less" />
<script src="less.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

All existing CSS files are also valid LESS files, so there's no cost of moving from CSS to LESS.

SASS and Stylus provide more power than LESS, but require a build system. Having a dedicated build system in place is recommended for serious projects, though. If you have a build system in place, then you could move directly to SASS. The SCSS variant of SASS is also drop-in compatible with CSS, but not with LESS.

Comment: Thank you for the very great and detailed information, exactly what I'm looking for.